# I'm a bit freaked out by the biome spread thing. What should I do?

Tags: terraria

I want to keep my hallow 2/3 biomes away, no Crimson (my 4 block, one in the Jungle) 2 biomes away. Only Corruption on the edges of my world, 1 to 2 biomes away, 3 to 4 biomes away. Not right next to what was Jerry's house! (The Tavernkeep)

Answer (score -1):

The best way to counter Biome Spread is the [Clentaminator](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Clentaminator). You can use different types of solution to spread certain biomes.

- Green Solution removes the Corruption, Crimson, and Hollow. This can be bought from the [Steampunker](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Steampunker) while their living in the Forest biome.
- Blue Solution spreads the Hollow. This can be bought from the [Steampunker](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Steampunker) while they live in the Hollow.
- Purple and Red Solution spread the Corruption / Crimson. These can be bought from the [Steampunker](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Steampunker) during a [Blood Moon](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blood_Moon) or a [Solar Eclipse](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Solar_Eclipse).

It should also be noted that after you beat [Planatara](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Plantera) the biome spread begins to slow. While it still spreads quickly it does become more manageable.

And [Sunflowers](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sunflower) do prevent the Corruption / Crimson from spreading. It's only a 5 tile radius so the corruption can simply go under the sunflower but this can keep NPC's in houses that they would have moved out of if the Sunflower wasn't there.

Comment: Don't u need to defeat a mech boss for the the Steampunker, because we started 2 days ago and we haven't had any different weapons or changes. So should I wait to get Orichalaucum or Cobalt Amour till I'm ready for battle.... Or just go straight into doing it!:)

Comment: You should get the best gear for your class. The Mechanical Bosses are a very tough trio to beat. @Decimal987